# getQuantityString returns part of string when quanitity is "one

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a quantity string in my app with two items, like so:

**strings.xml:**

```
<resources>
...
    <plurals name="daily_day_number">
        <item quantity="one">"Displaying 1 day"</item>
        <item quantity="other">Displaying %d days</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Inside a Fragment, i programatically set the value with `databinding` while using `getQuantityString` inside a method that's called in onCreateView, where `displayedDays` is an Int with a value of 1-5, passed as the quantity and variable arguments to `getQuantityString`:

**DailyFragment.kt:**

```
class DailyFragment : Fragment(), NetworkRequestListenerDaily {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentDailyBinding
    .....

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentDailyBinding.inflate(inflater)
        initUiDaily()
        return binding.root
    }

    .....

    private fun initUiDaily() {
        binding.apply {
            ......

            dailyDaysDisplay.text = resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.daily_day_number, displayedDays, displayedDays)
        }
    }
}
```

When the value of displayed days is > 1, the string is displayed correctly with the full text being displayed along with the passed in variable. when `displayedDays` is 1, the string being displayed is "day" (the last word in the "one" quantity item) instead of the full string.
Trying to pass 1 as a variable (`<item quantity="one">"Displaying %dd day"</item>`) results in the same behaviour. I've also made sure using the Evaluator that the value of `displayedDays` is indeed 1.

**fragment_daily.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="daily"
            type="com.example.myApp.networking.modules.daily.ApiResponseDaily" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daily_days_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            .....
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: why `%dd` and not just `%d`? Not sure if that's related. Just want to know. Also, it is recommended that `%d` should be included in the plural for `one`.

Comment: @KyzerSoze You have a point, seems like when ```displayedDays``` > 1 it works also with ```%d```, i followed some online guides and in one it appeared this way, that's why. I've updated my post. unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue when ```displayedDays``` is 1